# i can't make hibernate sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate

hi i am a noob programmer.

I am learning Hibernate now. And I am frustrated by

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM zipcode a 
WHERE (ISNULL( :sido , '') = '' OR a.sido = :sido) AND
 (ISNULL( :sigungu , '') = '' OR a.sigungu = :sigungu) AND
  (ISNULL( :eupmyun , '') = '' OR a.eupmyun = :eupmyun) AND
  (ISNULL( :roadName , '') = '' OR a.road_name = :roadName) AND
  (ISNULL( :ri , '') = '' OR a.ri = :ri)
```

I can't make this sql query to hibernate....

```
Number num = (Number) session()
                .createQuery(
                        "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ZipCode a WHERE (ISNULL( :sido , '') = '' OR a.sido = :sido) AND (ISNULL( :sigungu , '') = '' OR a.sigungu = :sigungu) AND (ISNULL( :eupmyun , '') = '' OR a.eupmyun = :eupmyun) AND(ISNULL( :roadName , '') = '' OR a.roadName = :roadName) AND(ISNULL( :ri , '') = '' OR a.ri = :ri)  ")
                .setParameter("sido", sido).setParameter("sigungu", sigungu).setParameter("eupmyun", eupmyun).setParameter("roadName", roadName).setParameter("ri", ri)
                .list();
```

I try this sql...
I am using Postgresql 9.4 and hibernate 5.0.*

Please help me

Comment: PostgreSQL has a bug, which they don't think it's a bug, where a NULL has one of 100+ data types, but cannot be converted between most of them. You should avoid using `setParameter(something,null)` as much as possible, unless you plan on switching databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** Instead of `createQuery` use `createSQLQuery` as below:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM zipcode a 
                      WHERE (ISNULL( :sido , '') = '' OR a.sido = :sido) AND
                     (ISNULL( :sigungu , '') = '' OR a.sigungu = :sigungu) AND
                     (ISNULL( :eupmyun , '') = '' OR a.eupmyun = :eupmyun) AND         
                     (ISNULL( :roadName , '') = '' OR a.road_name = :roadName) AND
                    (ISNULL( :ri , '') = '' OR a.ri = :ri) ");

Number number =(Number)query.list().get(0);
```

`createQuery` - is a HQL query whereas `createSQLQuery` is a native db query.

**Note:** make sure the query is in one line else you need to add ('+') concat operator.